# List<T>.Insert() out of bounds? C#

Tags: c#, list, insert

I am attempting to add a value to a list at a specific index, which according to everything I've read, should be do-able with List's `Insert()` method.

Except I'm getting the exception "Index must be within the bounds of the List. Parameter name: index`

Here is my complete sample code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyList myList = new MyList();
    }
}
class MyList : List<int>
{
    public MyList()
    {
        this.Capacity = 2;
        this.Insert(1, 0);
    }
}
```

Is the only option to change to a nullable list type and call `.Add(null)` for each index and not use `Insert()`?

Comment: 1. Lists are nullable 2. List/arrays start at 0. Your list has no entries, and you're trying to insert a value at the second position.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You're actually not supposed to be inheriting from `List<>` anyways. Just use composition and store a reference to one.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot insert an item beyond the last item, this is why you got the error message of out of bounds.

Setting the capacity of a list can be interesting if you know in advance that the list would not grow above a certain size, the Capacity.

Setting the capacity does not create any elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

- Capacity is not equal to size of the list, its the internal size before it internally resizes , its for performance
- Lists don't start at 1, they start at 0

[List.Capacity Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the total number of elements the internal data structure
>   can hold without resizing.

You are trying to add something to a bucket that doesn't exist

**Update**

> I'm trying to insert an item after the last index, that's the point of
>   using 1.

From your code you don't have anything at 0 to add anything at 1

Add something to 0 first before you add something to 1

Also don't inherit form list, its bad form for lots of reasons.

```
var myAwesomeList = new List<int>();
// add the number 10
myAwesomeList.Add(10);
// insert the number 7 before 10
myAwesomeList.Insert(0,7);
```

Comment: I'm trying to insert an item after the last index, that's the point of using 1. Is there a way to set the size?

Comment: @UpTide "After the last index" -> the last index in an _empty_ list is effectively `-1`, surely?

Comment: This question is solved elsewhere on stackoverflow. I'm going to mark this as duplicate.

Comment: @UpTide as you wish, it would pay to spend 5 minutes searching before you ask a question next time

Comment: @TheGeneral as usual my problem was not knowing what the problem was named. Namely your first sentence of "Capacity is not equal to size", which sparked the search for "how to set size of list c#". `List<T>` does not have a property called `Size`, it's not as intuitive as you would think (especially with a property called `Capacity`).

Comment: @UpTide i understand your frustration and i remember making it once myself, however the Microsoft documentation is pretty handy https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @TheGeneral this is just one of those things you have to "know" since setting size isn't mentioned on the List<T> page or the page for the specific exception I had.